# How do I make object A fail validation when its has-a object B fails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that contains the data to create a Product object. The Product has a relationship with an Image like so:

```
has_one :image
```

In my view I have a file input like so:

```
<%= f.file_field :image_file %>
```

In my Product model I have:

```
  def image_file=(input_data)
    self.image = Image.new({:image_file => input_data})
  end
```

The image model knows how to deal with the input_data and has validation rules for it.
The problem is that if the validation fails, my product gets created without an image.

**How do I make the validation errors ripple back to the Product, so that the Product does not get created at all and so I can show the errors on the form?**

As I'm new to Rails, if I'm doing it all wrong please tell me so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it by creating a custom validator:

```
validate :associated_image
```

This is the method:

```
def associated_image
  if image && !image.valid?
    image.errors.each { |attr, msg| errors.add(:image_file, msg)}
  end
end
```

Thanks to Gareth for pointing me to `validates_associated`, but the problem with it is that you lose the actual error messages from the associated object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002171) for that

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I was looking for. However, it outputs a default error message, it doesn't seem like I can get to the actual error message from the failed validation, can I?